# Textfield show console result

Tags: java

I'm doing my school assignment. My teacher wants me to make an application that has a layout to interact with people. So I want to interact with people by using something that I haven't found out yet, I think that thing is text field. Can I use text field as an console screen or I should use another way? 
Thank you!

Comment: Hint: take a look at Scanner and use the console, using any type of GUI will be more complicated and it looks like you are just getting started. Good luck!

Comment: Please describe your Question a little bit more... In a Textfield you can put informations, this Informations you get with this function: textfield.getText();@IdusOrtus he don't like to get a Solution like you told him

Comment: @Lukas if his professor wanted him to use a GUI of some sort he would have provided a lesson on it prior. Based upon the caliber of question Id place Lemans in Java 101 which typically covers user interaction using the console. But, to be fair to you, the question doesnt provide much for us to go on.

Comment: Okay :D It was not a strike against you, calm down ;)

Comment: Hi, my teacher want me to do something like this: "https://www.dropbox.com/s/ua7gzfz7gdsai2j/a.jpg?dl=0" @LukasHieronimusAdler

Answer (score 1):

The MessageConsole class will enable you to use a text area or text pane as a simple console. First you must decide which component to use:

```
JTextArea – will be more efficient
JTextPane – will allow you to color the text from each source
```

Next you must decide how you want the console to function:

```
append – messages will be added to the bottom of the console
insert – messages will be inserted as the first line of the console
```

Finally, you need to decide if you need to limit the number of lines contained in the console. The `MessageConsole` will use my `LimitLinesDocumentListener`

```
somePanel.add( new JScrollPane( textComponent ) );
MessageConsole mc = new MessageConsole(textComponent);
mc.redirectOut();
mc.redirectErr(Color.RED, null);
mc.setMessageLines(100)
```

One last comment. You can optionally redirect the message to a PrintStream. So if you did something like the following:

```
mc.redirectOut(null, System.out);
```